# how to naturally rotate a ball according to its velocity on a surface, a wall

Tags: rotation, cocos2d-x, sprite, velocity

I am developing a game in cocos2d-x which has a ball sprite in it. I move the ball on a surface(wall) via touch events. Is it possible to rotate the ball naturally according to its velocity?

if i use ballSprite->runAction(..) in update(float dt) method then it doesn't rotate.

i use the following code:

```
void GameLayer::updateBall(float dt)
{
  float deltaRotateX = 360.0f * _ballVelocityX;
  _ballSprite->setRotation(90.0f- CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(deltaRotateX));
}
```

But the ball doesn't naturally rotate. it discretely rotates.
it can't naturally rotate according to its velocity.

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing degress and radians. You're multipling times 360 and later convert it from radians to degress.

Answer (score 0):

You question could mean a few things. Do you want to ball rotate while "rolling" on a surface? Do you want the ball to always rotate depending on the velocity it's moving at? Do you want the ball to rotate a certain way after bouncing off the wall? all of these have separate answers.

For your question I will assume that you want to drag the ball on your wall, and it must "roll" as it's moving. To achieve this behavior would be difficult to couple with velocity since you are "dragging" the ball and it's not being moved based on motion. So I would just update my rotation of my sprite with the delta the ball moved in my onTouchMoved function.

```
ballSprite->setRotation(ballSprite->getRotation() + touch->getDelta().distance);
```

This will cause your sprite to rotate as the player drags it across the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Vec2 _lastBallPosition;//Declare this in your header file, it represents the las position of your ball

void GameLayer::updateBall(float dt)
{

    if (!_lastBallPosition.equals(getPosition())) {
        Vec2 delta=getPosition()-_lastBallPosition;
        setRotation(getRotation()+ delta.length());
       _lastBallPosition=getPosition();
    }

}
```

Use `CCPoint` instead of `Vec2` if your cocos2dx version is < 3.0